# Log4j separate logs

Tags: log4j, package

I am trying to write separate logs for different packages using log4j. I am able to write separate logs for different levels using a customize appender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two appender like this:

```
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE.File=/abc.log
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE1.File=/abcde.log
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE1.Append=true
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MYLOGFILE1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Then you define your packages:

```
log4j.logger.mypackage=MYLOGFILE
log4j.additivity.mypackage=false


log4j.logger.secondpackage=MYLOGFILE1
log4j.additivity.secondpackage=false
```

The last line(additivity) is needed to not have your package inherit the global appender. Doing so will result in the log messages from mypackage also printed at the default appender.